# What is the best place to loop through the props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What is the best place to loop through the props and construct my element in react .

I can achieve using both constructor and render methods which one is more feasible

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Since props can change, it's best to derive your UI from props in the `render` method if you can.